# How to use markdown for wordpress posts

Tags: php, wordpress, xampp, markdown

I've installed and set up `XAMPP` (v. 5.6.30-1) and `Wordpress` (v. 4.8) for some tests and I want to write posts in markdown.

I found this [official support document](https://en.support.wordpress.com/markdown/), stating that markdown support can simply be enabled in the settings, but this option is not available for me (see screenshot below).

[image: No markdown option]

Then I tried to install the [JP Markdown plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jetpack-markdown/), which kind of works, but only partially.

[image: kind of markdown]

Most of the markdown works, but for example headings do not work.

My question is: Why don't I have the options as officially stated by wordpress, to enable markdown?

And how do I enable a proper markdown editor for wordpress posts?

Comment: It could be theme related, what theme are you using?

Comment: The default `"Twenty Seventeen" Version: 1.3 by the WordPress team`

Answer (score 1):

The documentation you found was for wordpress.com

You want the Jetpack plugin. It should provide the features you want.

Comment: Thank you, I've realised that by now. The Jetpack plugin would work for me, but it feels like that's crazy overkill for markdown support only.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve tested most of the markdown plugins out there, including jetpack, discarded them either because they are old and unsupported or because they … how to put it without using odd words? … don’t suit my needs or are an overkill. That was polite enough. You get the idea.

I found this one, [easy markdown](https://github.com/DavidWells/easy-markdown), almost by accident and loved it.

It’s intended to be used without the visual editor (actually the author tells you to deactivate it), but if you are going to use markdown, you don’t need it.
It has to be installed manually, but it’s worth it, and explained on its github page.

- It supports syntax highlighting for code blocks right away.
- It modifies the editor so that you can use tabs in your text. Yes, when typing inside the editor the [tab] key produce a tab, doesn't jump the focus to the next form field, and you can do multiline tab insertion and deletion.
- You can still use shortcodes.
- You can still use html if you need to do so.

I liked it so much that I even contributed to the github project by making the tab insertion feature more robust.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may try this [WordPress Markdown Plugin](https://terryl.in/en/repository/wordpress-markdown-plugin-githuber-md/)

Source code: https://github.com/terrylinooo/githuber-md

DEMO:

[image]

[image]